# Is a Hermitian matrix squared a positive matrix?

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

If I have a Hermitian matrix, $H=H^{\dagger}$, is the square of this matrix a positive matrix? i.e. is $A=HH$ positive?

Numerically this appears to be true but I don't know the proof of this.

Comment: Any thoughts about it? What's your definition of a positive matrix? Do you know any other results along these lines?

Comment: Hint: A matrix $X$ is positive semidefinite iff it can be written as $X = Y^{\dagger}Y$ for some matrix $Y$.

Comment: @SampleTime that is not self-adjoint.

Comment: @Rammus Good point.

Comment: Almost. A hermitian Matrix has real eigenvalues, therefore its square has non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for the points guys. I have got it now. Sorry for wasting your time with something that ended up being trivial

Comment: Is your question on positivity or positive (semi)definiteness?